# Does grep support the OR in a group?

Tags: shell, grep

I am looking at this question: https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-phone-numbers/

which asked using a cmd to extract the phone numbers.

I found this command works:

```
cat file.txt | grep -Eo '^(\([0-9]{3}\) ){1}[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$|^([0-9]{3}-){2}[0-9]{4}$'
```

while this failed:

```
cat file.txt | grep -E '(^(\([0-9]{3}\))|^([0-9]{3}-))[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}'
```

I don't know why the second failed. Does it because **grep** doesn't support OR in a group?

Comment: The question you link to has a strong American cultural bias.  That's not a reasonable division between "valid" and "invalid" phone numbers in many parts of the world.

Comment: Specifying a single repetition of something with `{1}` is completely redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's because you dropped the space, so space in a phone number will no longer be allowed.

Also, the grouping in your regex seems to be off by a whack or two.  What are you actually trying to express?

Finally, you have a [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) -- `grep` can perfectly well read one or more input files without the help of `cat`.